# Clicked series to be highlighted and other series to be shown as little faded

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following the implementation of the kendo chart and now i have requirement is

Clicked series to show as normal and the other series to be faded ( some opacity to be set)

How can this be achieved in the kendo chart type:bar

```
seriesClick: function (e) {
   var clickedSeries = e.series.name;
   var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.series.length; i++) {
        chart.toggleHighlight(false, chart.options.series[i].name);
     }
   chart.toggleHighlight(true, clickedSeries);
}
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kcbvtutu/

Comment: you want someone to write it all for you? have you attempted to do anything about this yourself?

Comment: I tired but not able to achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: Doesn't look like you tried anything to be perfectly frank. you have a var named `clickedSeries` but that's in a function named `seriesHover` ... changing the var name to something with click in it is hardly an attempt to get click working ... but, you may be lucky, someone may have an answer for you - good luck

Comment: Apologies earlier i had this in hover now i changed to click . Nothing much about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set the opacity of the series in the loop then it worked.

```
seriesClick: function (e) {
   var clickedSeries = e.series.name;
   var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.series.length; i++) {
        chart.toggleHighlight(false, chart.options.series[i].name);
        item.opacity = 0.3
     }
   chart.toggleHighlight(true, clickedSeries);
}
```

Just added the below line in the loop

```
item.opacity = 0.3
```

Then it worked.